# VLCJ: Can't disable subtitle

Tags: java, libvlc, vlcj

I tried to disable the subtitles by

```
mediaPlayer.setSubTitleFile((String)null);
mediaPlayer.setSubTitleFile((File)null);
```

Also tried,

```
mediaPlayer.cycleSpu();
```

And,

```
mediaPlayer.setSpu(-1);
```

Also, I tried to list the available tracks using `getTrackInfo()`
The result consisted only of a single TrackInfo

```
TextTrackInfo[codec=0x74627573,codecName=subt,originalCodec=0x74627573,originalCodecName=subt,id=2,profile=-1,level=-1,bitRate=0,language=null,description=null][encoding=null]
```

> According to the javadocs, there must be a `TextTrack` named disable which can be set to display using `setSpu()`, so that there won't be any subtitles.

But in my case there's no `TextTrack` named disable

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

try to use this method

```
public void ShowSubtitles() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AnnotationTool.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    sub = mediaplayer.getMediaPlayer().getSpuDescriptions();
    for (TrackDescription tr : sub) {
        System.out.println("TrackDescription"+tr.description());
    }
    if (sub.size() > 0) {
        mediaplayer.getMediaPlayer().setSpu(sub.get(0).id());
    }
}
```

this method will solve your problem